# Log-in to Microsoft 365 apps fails when on wifi only, on some phones

Tags: networking, onedrive, microsoft-word

I am playing around with Microsoft Intune enrollment of Android phones, and I have noticed that I am partially able to use Microsoft 365 apps for Android.

I have 2 phones, that are wifi-only.

- A fully managed Huawei P10 lite running Android 8
- A Fairphone 2 running Android 10 with a work-profile

Both phones can connect to the internet, enrol into Microsoft Intune, install apps.

However, only the Huawei is able to log-in with the Microsoft 365 Office apps, i.e., OneDrive et al.; the Fairphone 2 fails with the error message declaring that no network connection is available.

My Google results are full of similar complaints, however, there's either no possible solution posted, or some seemingly random "tips" such as clearing the app's cache, un-installing and re-installing (an all time Microsoft-support classic), and more various and wonderful actions to take.

I have seen suggestions to change DNS settings to use e.g. the 8.8.8.8 DNS server from Google, however, our guest wifi already uses this DNS; to no avail. While all other apps connect to the internet, Microsoft'S finest 365 apps for Android are blissfully unaware of the available network.

Has anyone from this community some wisdom to share?

---

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/my-phone-app-says-i-dont-have-internet-connection/88010637-227d-4f4f-bfc4-aa9ffac5c139

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/cant-login-to-microsoft-android-apps-with-wifi/52b3a6ed-8f7b-4ddb-92d8-a907b87cfd92

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/office-apps-on-android-problem-on-wifi/2e891a9f-9784-45b9-8a00-5c9513448dd3